# Proper use of <use> and <svg>

Tags: svg

I'm referencing an svg file's content from my html, like this:

```
<svg id='container' width="19" height="19">
    <use href="../svg.svg#path"/>
</svg>
```

svg.svg

```
<svg
    id="home"
    width="19"
    height="19"
    viewBox="0 0 19 19"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path id='path' fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M6.10156 2.31433C4.85892 2.31433
            3.85156 3.32169 3.85156 4.56433V7.27979L5.21733 6.15722C5.88058 5.61207 6.84134 5.62857 7.48549
            6.19616L11.5046 9.7376C11.8811 10.0694 12.0971 10.547 12.0976 11.0489L12.1032 16.8638H14.6256C15.8682
            16.8638 16.8756 15.8565 16.8756 14.6138V4.56433C16.8756 3.32169 15.8682 2.31433 14.6256 2.31433H6.10156ZM2.35156
            4.56433V8.51269L0.879033 9.72301C0.474603 10.0554 0.240234 10.5514 0.240234 11.0749L0.240249
            16.6071C0.240252 17.5731 1.02297 18.3564 1.98897 18.3571L12.1047 18.3645L12.1047 18.3638H14.6256C16.6966
            18.3638 18.3756 16.6849 18.3756 14.6138V4.56433C18.3756 2.49326 16.6966 0.814331 14.6256 0.814331H6.10156C4.03049
            0.814331 2.35156 2.49326 2.35156 4.56433ZM6.49381 7.32159C6.40179 7.2405 6.26454 7.23814 6.16979 7.31602L1.83149 10.8818C1.77372 10.9293 1.74023 11.0002 1.74023 11.0749L1.74025 16.6071C1.74025 16.7451 1.85207 16.857 1.99007 16.8571L5.42188 16.8596V14.1996C5.42188 13.7854 5.75766 13.4496 6.17188 13.4496C6.58609 13.4496 6.92188 13.7854 6.92188 14.1996V16.8607L10.6032 16.8634L10.5976 11.0503C10.5975 10.9786 10.5667 10.9104 10.5129 10.863L6.49381 7.32159Z" />
</svg>
```

Question is:

1. Why do I need to set `width` and `height` in `container`? If I fail to do so, `container` takes up 150px by 300px.
2. How could I just make `container` automatically shrink to fit `home`'s dimensions?

Thanks

Comment: 1. are you referring to *Why do I need to set width and height in container?* 2. I would prefer not using images because I need to modify the svg style via JS. But maybe that´s not what you meant, could you elaborate? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The HTML spec says that if the size of any "replaced element" (that's things like `<svg>`, `<canvas>`, `<object>` etc) is not specified, then its size should default to 300px x 150px.

   The `<use>` points to a `<path>`, rather than a whole SVG image, so it's size is indeterminate.
2. Given your use case, you cannot.

Comment: what if `<use>` pointed to `#home` instead of `#path`? would it make any difference?

Comment: No difference. All you would be doing is embedding a child `<svg>` within a parent `<svg>` of unspecified dimensions.